# Need foxpro dbf recovery tool

Tags: windows, dbf, visual-foxpro

How to avoid mistakes 41 (DataBase.dct)? I work in FoksPro. My file is corrupted. How to save me my table?
On kompyuetere besides my other work tasks .Klient turns my task and work in another, then back at me and an error is 41, that is corrupt memo-file database. Sometimes peeled off the first file in the database and the file is checked.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

In FoxPro (VisualFoxPro), if you have a database container, you will have files with the extensions of

```
.DBC  -- The .dbf equivalent representing the database container
.DCX  -- The .cdx equivalent representing the indexes for the database container
.DCT  -- The .fpt equivalent (memo file content) for the database container.
```

So, if the database container is whacked, you may just need to go to backups as the database container really doesn't change much.

If you have a specific individual table (based on actual .dbf, .cdx, .fpt file extensions), then the memo file could be corrupt.  I don't know of an easy way to repair corrupt memo files, but did write an answer out here on how the .FPT file is formatted to get the content out at low-level file handling.

That said, can you confirm if it is a database container corruption, or an individual table corruption... And also if an individual table, how large is the file and how critical is the content of the memo file content to the table vs something like generic notes that could be easily done via manual re-entry (in case partial recovery of memo is possible).

Answer (score 2):

If a .FPT, .VCT or .DCT is missing, you must replace it.  You might have to get it from a backup.  If you can't get it from a backup, you will have to re-create the file.

If it is corrupted, you can [look for a tool to repair it](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=vfp%20repair%20memo%20file).  It's hard, though.